# How to close the spark instance

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I want to stop my spark instance here once I complete my job running on Jupyter notebook.
I did execute `spark.stop()` at the end, but when I open my terminal, I'm still see the spark process there `ps -ef | grep spark` So everytime I have to kill spark process ID manually. Anyone knows how to solve this problem? Thanks!!

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local") \
    .appName("Test") \
    .config("spark.executorEnv.PYTHONPATH", "pyspark.zip:py4j-0.10.7-src.zip")\
    .config('spark.jars','/Users/xxx/Documents/snowflake-jdbc-3.12.8.jar,/Users/xxx/Documents/spark-snowflake_2.11-2.7.2-spark_2.4.jar') \
    .config('spark.jars.packages','org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3') \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 7):

Try by shutting down the sparkContext instead of spark session.
You can Try following things:

```
sc.stop()
```

or

```
spark.sparkContext.stop()
```

and than you can do

```
spark.stop()
```

Comment: I can still see process id in my terminal after trying to do above steps.

Answer (score 0):

I've had luck closing the session running:

```
exit()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).